# sddm + pam_kwallet5 + pam_usb = "open_session called without kwallet5_key"

Tags: pam, kwallet, sddm

With pam_usb set up and running, when the usb key is connected when I type password in SDDM, after Plasma started up, I see that kwallet is not unlocked. This does not happen when usb key is inserted *after* I logged in. When the issue appears, I can see the subjected message in the log:

```
18 00:05:01 rocket sddm-helper[3172]: pam_kwallet(sddm:session): (null): pam_sm_open_session
18 00:05:01 rocket sddm-helper[3172]: pam_kwallet(sddm:session): pam_kwallet: open_session called without kwallet_key
18 00:05:01 rocket sddm-helper[3172]: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): (null): pam_sm_open_session
18 00:05:01 rocket sddm-helper[3172]: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: open_session called without kwallet5_key
```

Here are related pam-files:

`cat /etc/pam.d/common-auth|grep -v "^#"`

```
auth    sufficient      pam_usb.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

`cat /etc/pam.d/sddm|grep -v "^#"`

```
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success

@include common-auth
-auth   optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
-auth   optional        pam_kwallet.so
-auth   optional        pam_kwallet5.so

@include common-account

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_loginuid.so
session required        pam_systemd.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
-session optional       pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
-session optional       pam_kwallet.so auto_start
-session optional       pam_kwallet5.so auto_start

@include common-password


session required        pam_env.so

session required        pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

How can I configure pam_usb and pam_kwallet(5) to live together?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything better than:

`cat /etc/pam.d/common-auth`

```
auth sufficient pam_usb.so
@include common-auth-nousb
```

`cat /etc/pam.d/common-auth-nousb`

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

`head /etc/pam.d/sddm`

```
#%PAM-1.0

# Block login if they are globally disabled
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success

# auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth-nousb
# gnome_keyring breaks QProcess
-auth   optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

This makes `pam-auth-update` useless, but achieves the goal: now I can boot with key flash drive inserted without the need to unlock kwallet manually.